# Joomla Sites .htaccess keeps getting hacked

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I am running 1.5.25 and somehow a .htaccess file keeps getting created on my root.

```
ErrorDocument 400 http:// redirected url index.php                                                                                                                      
ErrorDocument 404 http:// redirected url index.php  index.php                                                                                                                       
ErrorDocument 500 http://redirected url /index.php  

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                        
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(google|ask|yahoo|baidu|youtube|wikipedia|qq|excite|altavista|msn|netscape|aol|hotbot|goto|infoseek|mamma|alltheweb|lycos|search|metacrawler|bing|dogpile|facebook|twitter|blog|live|myspace|mail|yandex|rambler|ya|aport|linkedin|flickr)\.(.*)                                                                                                                     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://redirected url index.php   [R=301,L]                                                                                                                      
</IfModule>
```

I would like to know how to find out who creates this .htaccess file even when deleted. Is there a away to find out which script creates this? Which user creates it?

Anyone who has had this problem before? Is there a way I can create a .htaccess and disable it from being changed. Applying 644 permission setting does not seem to help.

NOTE: I have changed actual redirect URL to redirected url index.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming, belongs to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a good first check is to see if there are any cronjobs who do this (crontab -l). Some hosting panels have cleanup actions and only allow modification of the .htaccess by using their UI (so it gets stored in a database first).

This might get you underway as well; http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring

Comment: $ crontab -l does not give me much. All lines are commented. I am using SSH to connect to the dreamhost server so I dont think I can install that filechecker app on it.

Comment: I updated my answer, seems like the previous suggestions was windows-only. This should accomodate your needs much better.

Answer (score 5):

Erm permissions 644 means the file is writeable - by the owner at least. I don't know how the server is set up and whether the owner is you (the ftp user) or 'nobody' the web server.

Chances are you have either an outdated version of Joomla with a vulnerability or an outdated and vulnerable add-on. Chances are high that someone has used a vulnerability to drop a 'web shell' into your file system. This allows him to connect to the file and provides him with a control panel of options to edit files, upload files, run arbitrary commands.

It could be that another account on the server is compromised and then files within that account reach out and make edits server wide - or at least on any writable files/folders on the server.

You should really get help from a web security expert, but if you wish to try and do the analysis yourself here are a few steps to take.

On the server, you can also search the file system using the 'find' command, to find files changed in the last x days, or last x hours.

You need to take the site offline, contact your host and explain the issue and see what info they can provide. You should download your files and as a first measure run the through a powerful virus scanner (these identify most web shells nowadays).

Search through the files for the following words/patterns - grep or similar are useful for these:

web\s*shell

hacked\s*by

r57

c99

base64_decode

The lines with \s* are regular expressions.
The last one will provide many false positives - examine each file for anything suspicious, files that don't look like Joomla code (obviously requires a bit of familiarity to spot).

Upgrade Joomla and any add-ons that have more up-to-date versions. Start by searching http://exploit-db.com/ for 'joomla' and see if any of your add-ons are listed.

http://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&filter_page=1&filter_exploit_text=joomla&filter_platform=0&filter_type=0&filter_lang_id=0

There are many many other things that can be checked, and probably should be checked - but these are a good starting point - but I do stress that it is best to retain the help of someone who is experienced at this stuff.  De-hacking services typically start at £500 and rise to approx £1,000 ($800 - $1600).

When you put the site back live check that 
register_globals are off
short open tags are off

Make sure the following functions are disabled via the this disable_functions directive in php.ini
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

Answer (score 4):

For a Secured Joomla site you can use below code, just edit your `.htaccess` file and below ships with full protection for Joomla site. Also It will update your URL using Joomla Core SEF(You have to enable it). Go to Admin panel and update your Mode/ReadWrite of Apache.

You can use below code

```
RewriteEngine On        
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes

FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresActive On

# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"

# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 year after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 year"

# Audio files expiration: 1 year after request
ExpiresByType audio/basic "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/mid "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/midi "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-mpegurl "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "now plus 1 year"

# Movie files expiration: 1 year after request
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType x-world/x-vrml "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/quicktime "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/x-la-asf "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/x-ms-asf "now plus 1 year"

########## End - Optimal expiration time

########## Begin - block bandwidth hoggers 

SetEnvIf user-agent "Indy Library" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "libwww-perl" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Wget" stayout=1

# The following rules are for bandwidth-hogging download tools
SetEnvIf user-agent "Download Demon" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "GetRight" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "GetWeb!" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Go!Zilla" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Go-Ahead-Got-It" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "GrabNet" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "TurnitinBot" stayout=1

# This line denies access to all of the above tools
deny from env=stayout
########## End - block bandwidth hoggers 


# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml, kudos to Komra.de
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
########## End - Automatic compression of resources

########## Begin - Google Apps redirection, by Sashi
Redirect 301 /mail http://mail.google.com/a/
########## End - Google Apps redirection

########## Begin - Redirect index.php to /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R,L]
########## End - Redirect index.php to /

########## Begin - Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
########## End - Redirect non-www to www

########## Begin - Redirect www to non-www
## WARNING: Comment out the non-www to www rule if you choose to use this
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R,L]
########## End - Redirect non-www to www

########## Begin - Redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
########## End - Redirect example.com to www.example.com

########## Begin - Force HTTPS for certain pages

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^foobar\.html$ https://www.example.com/foobar.html [L,R]
# Add mode rules below this line


########## Block bad user agents

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
 ## Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.

 ## Return 403 Forbidden error.
 RewriteRule .* - [F]

 ServerSignature Off
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D) [NC,OR]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(,|;|:|<|>|”>|”<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999} [NC,OR]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (libwww-perl|curl|wget|python|nikto|scan) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]

 #Block mySQL injects
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|’|”|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark) [NC,OR]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./\.\. [OR]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.[a-z0-9] [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC]
 # Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.

 # Return 403 Forbidden error.
 RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

########## Begin - File injection protection

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]\=http:\/\/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End


## Allow UddeIM CAPTCHA
RewriteRule ^(components/com_uddeim/captcha15\.php)$ $1 [L]

## Allow Phil Taylor's Turbo Gears
RewriteRule ^(plugins/system/GoogleGears/gears-manifest\.php) $1 [L]

## Allow JoomlaWorks AllVideos
RewriteRule ^(plugins/content/jw_allvideos/includes/jw_allvideos_scripts\.php) $1 [L]

# Add more rules to single PHP files here

## Allow Agora attachments, but not PHP files in that directory!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(components/com_agora/img/members/.*) $1 [L]

# Add more rules for allowing full access (except PHP files) on more directories here

## Uncomment to allow full access to the cache directory (strongly not recommended!)
#RewriteRule ^(cache/.*)$ $1 [L]

## Uncomment to allow full access to the tmp directory (strongly not recommended!)
#RewriteRule ^(tmp/.*)$ $1 [L]

# Add more full access rules here

########## End - Advanced server protection rules exceptions ####

RewriteRule ^(images/stories/*\.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow visual fingerprinting of Joomla! sites (module position dump)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl=component [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tp= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)template= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow PHP Easter Eggs (can be used in fingerprinting attacks to determine
## your PHP version). See http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php and
## http://osvdb.org/12184 for more information
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =PHP[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Back-end protection
## This also blocks fingerprinting attacks browsing for XML and INI files
RewriteRule ^(administrator[/]?)$ administrator/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index.htm[l]?)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index[2,3].php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/(components|modules|templates|images|plugins)/.*\.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Explicitly allow access only to XML-RPC's xmlrpc/index.php or plain xmlrpc/ directory
RewriteRule ^(xmlrpc/index\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^xmlrpc/(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow front-end access for certain Joomla! system directories
RewriteRule ^(includes/js/.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(cache|includes|language|libraries|logs|tmp)/.*$ - [F,L]

## Allow limited access for certain Joomla! system directories with client-accessible content
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*\.(jp[g,2,eg]?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*index\.php(.*))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(templates/.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*$ - [F,L]

## Disallow access to htaccess.txt and configuration.php-dist
RewriteRule ^(htaccess\.txt|configuration\.php-dist)$ - [F,L]

## SQLi first line of defense
## May cause problems on legitimate requests

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union.*select.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union.*all.*select.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End - Advanced server protection

########## Begin - Basic antispam Filter
## I removed some common words, tweak to your liking

RewriteCond %{query_string} \bviagra\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bambien\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bblue\spill\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bcialis\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bcocaine\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bejaculation\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \berectile\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \berections\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bhoodia\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bhuronriveracres\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bimpotence\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \blevitra\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \blibido\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \blipitor\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bphentermin\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bprosac\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bsandyauer\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \btramadol\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \btroyhamby\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bultram\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bunicauca\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bvalium\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bviagra\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bvicodin\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bxanax\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bypxaieo\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End - Basic antispam Filter

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|\.ini|\.zip|\.json|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: Update http://www.xxx.com to http://www.yoursitename.com do not find and replace.

Comment: That looks a good list of filters, I would recommend putting them in the Apache conf files or vhost file rather than .htaccess if you can change that file on your host so that they are stored in memory and not rechecked on every page load

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code for your .htaccess file

```
## Disallow access to htaccess.txt and configuration.php-dist
RewriteRule ^(htaccess\.txt|configuration\.php-dist)$ - [F,L]
```

Below are few more setting for a secure .htaccess file

```
########## End - Advanced server protection rules exceptions ####

RewriteRule ^(images/stories/*\.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.xxx\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow visual fingerprinting of Joomla! sites (module position dump)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl=component [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tp= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)template= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow PHP Easter Eggs (can be used in fingerprinting attacks to determine
## your PHP version). See http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php and
## http://osvdb.org/12184 for more information
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =PHP[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Back-end protection
## This also blocks fingerprinting attacks browsing for XML and INI files
RewriteRule ^(administrator[/]?)$ administrator/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index.htm[l]?)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index[2,3].php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/(components|modules|templates|images|plugins)/.*\.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Explicitly allow access only to XML-RPC's xmlrpc/index.php or plain xmlrpc/ directory
RewriteRule ^(xmlrpc/index\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^xmlrpc/(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow front-end access for certain Joomla! system directories
RewriteRule ^(includes/js/.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(cache|includes|language|libraries|logs|tmp)/.*$ - [F,L]

## Allow limited access for certain Joomla! system directories with client-accessible content
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*\.(jp[g,2,eg]?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*index\.php(.*))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(templates/.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*$ - [F,L]

## Disallow access to htaccess.txt and configuration.php-dist
RewriteRule ^(htaccess\.txt|configuration\.php-dist)$ - [F,L]

## SQLi first line of defense
## May cause problems on legitimate requests

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union.*select.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union.*all.*select.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End - Advanced server protection
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a serious problem with someone hacking into my .htaccess file and my only solution was to make the file unhackable. First, I cleaned up the .htaccess file and any PHP files of all hacks. Then I changed the file permissions to 444 (644 still allows access) on the .htaccess file. Then I used the shell access to my account to make the file "immutable", which means it cannot be changed!

When you have shell access to your account on your Linux server, 
enter the following: # chattr +i .htaccess

Now, even those with root access cannot change the file!

It you need to undo this, enter: # chattr -i .htaccess

If you do not have shell access to your account, ask your web host about entering this for you to make the file immutable.

For non-Linux accounts, just enter "making file immutable" into Google or Bing for your type of web server. This should give you the information you need.